# New Samsung Note 9 battery charger compatibility

Tags: samsung, battery, charging, battery-life

I just bought a new Samsung Note 9 (Exynos 9810). Little did I know that the model I ordered was the EU version and not the US version, so the charger I received was unusable with any of my power sockets. I ordered an adapter online but thanks to my impatience, instead of waiting for the adapter - decided to just charge the new device for the first time with my old Asus Zenfone charger. The Note 9 charged pretty slowly, even though the Asus charger is a fast charger (5V, 2A or 9V, 2A similar to the Samsung's 5V, 2A or 9V, 1.67A). I charged it to 100%.

I've been experiencing pretty average battery life, which is weird since the Note 9 has a 4000mah battery. I have however been using the phone pretty heavily as I've been setting it up with my accounts. 
Did using the non-OEM charger for the first charge-up of the device - mess up the battery performance in any way?

I've been beating myself up over this, so I decided to do a Geekbench battery test (Partial Discharge), which returned a score of 4653 with "Medium confidence", which is lower than the score posted online (approx. 5000) However, I don't know if the online scores are for Partial Discharge, and the comparison scores my phone displayed for example for the Galaxy S8 were also lower on my phone than the ones posted online...

Am I worried over nothing? Would charging the battery for the first time with a non OEM charger hurt the battery/ phone? Is the battery charged at the factory with the OEM charger before it is sent to market?

Comment: Charging the device with a non-OEM charger is not likely to harm anything at all, as you have noted it will likely take longer. In fact it is probably better for the device to charge slower as there is less heat buildup in the battery while charging. And no, the battery is not charged with the OEM charger at the factory, the batteries are likely installed pre-charged prior to the package being sealed. Battery life is a tricky thing and can vary from device to device even within the same model do to a number of factors.

Comment: I agree.. just wondering if this being the first charge-up made any difference. FYI the battery was already at 48% out of the box when I charged it upto 100%. I expect the battery test results to be different... I'm gonna run the battery test once again to see how different it is just from instance to instance.

Comment: First charge up or last, shouldn't make a difference... although I don't have any information to verify that specifically. A slow charge is better for a battery than a fast one, regardless if it's the first or most recent charge. Most devices are shipped with the battery at 50-75%, as 50% is the optimal long-term storage level for LiOn or LiPo battery and their self-discharge rate is about 2-3% per month, plus keeping batteries stored at 100% or 0% charge is known to shorten their lifespan. BTW, I don't trust ANY of those battery testers in the real world, get GSAM and see where it's going.